# How can I format my java code with automating netbeans ide by autohotkey?

Tags: automation, autohotkey, code-formatting

I want to format selected java code with sending keys to hidden NetBeans IDE.I wrote following script

```
^+b::
sleep 30
Send ^c
sleep 30
run,C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans64.exe "C:\sample.java",Hide
sleep 1500
ControlSend,,{^v}, "Netbeans"
sleep 50
ControlSend,,{!+f}, "Netbeans" 
sleep 50
ControlSend,,{^a}, "Netbeans" 
sleep 50
ControlSend,,{^c}, "Netbeans" 
sleep 50
WinMinimize,"Netbeans"
sleep 100
Send, ^v
return
```

But hidden NetBeans pops up when trying to send keys with ControlSend and I can't minimize Netbeans window with WinMinimize,"Netbeans".How can I fix this issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to use quotes, your code won’t be working. And if you want, you don’t have to use commas.

This code works fine:

```
WinMinimize Netbeans
; WinMinimize, Netbeans ; this will work too
```

Using with commas:

```
WinMinimize % "Netbeans"
```

But since some programs use dynamic window name, you’d better minimize programs by their process name:

```
WinMinimize, ahk_exe netbeans.exe
```

Also, you can just minimize the active window:

```
WinMinimize A
```

More: https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot."WinMinimize, ahk_exe netbeans64.exe" works correctly.But ControlSend doesn't work with "ahk_exe netbeans64.exe".This is very strange.

Comment: `ControlSend` with `ahk_exe` works fine for me. Maybe you should use `{Ctrl down}{V}{Ctrl up}` instead of `{^v}`. Make sure you are not using `SendMode Input` in your code, because `input` mode is too rapid, thus a program won’t have time to receive a pressed key. If this still doesn’t work, you could set a timeout between `ctrl down` and `v`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use NetBeans so I can't experiment, but:

1. Double-click the tray icon of your script and run Window Spy.
2. Make sure you're detecting the right window, and you *might* have to experiment with "[SetTitleMatchMode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) RegEx" and refine your [WinTitle](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) string, but this might not be really necessary, as your `ControlSend` does seem to detect it correctly. However, I'd still make sure.
3. You might also have to use an alternative method for minimizing a window:
   From [WinMinimize](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm):
   `PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF020,,, WinTitle, WinText ; 0x112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF020 = SC_MINIMIZE`
4. What you really want to use might not be `WinMinimize`, but [`WinHide`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinHide.htm).

Comment: Is there any difference between `WinMinimize` and `WinHide`?

Comment: Of course. You'll see a big difference if you try it.